# Realification of Cauchy-Riemann Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

The Cauchy-Riemann equations turn a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map on the vector space $\mathbb{C}$ to a  $\mathbb{R}$-linear map on $\mathbb{R}^2$. This seems to imply that the two vector spaces are isomorphic. However even with the complex structure, $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{C}$ correct? Can the Cauchy-Riemann equations be explained somehow through the concept of a realification followed by complexification? If so, then how?

Comment: vector spaces over different fields cannot be isomorphic. The Cauchy-Riemann equations are the consequence of the derivative of a function $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ being represented by a complex-linear transformation $Df_p\in\mathcal{L}(\Bbb{C},\Bbb{C})$ (hence $Df_p$ is simply multiplication by a complex number: $Df_p(h)=f'(p)\cdot h$). If one considers $\Bbb{C}$ as a 2-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{R}$, then this gives rise to a $2\times 2$ matrix representation for $Df_p$, and it will have the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$. This special structure is precisely the CR eqn

Comment: That is precisely the question, how can one considers ℂ as a 2-dimensional vector space over  ℝ and go back?

Comment: any vector space $V$ over $\Bbb{C}$ automatically becomes a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$, because scalar multiplication is originally a mapping $\Bbb{C}\times V\to V$, so we can simply restrict to get $\Bbb{R}\times V \to V$. THe other direction, i.e starting with  real vector space $W$ and making a complex vector space is more involved. One needs a so called "complex structure", meaning a (real)-linear mapping $J:W\to W$ such that $J^2=-I_W$. Then, define complex scalar multiplication as $(a+bi)\cdot w = aw + bJ(w)$, so the endomorphism $J$ acts as multiplication by $i$.

Comment: Yes, those are the definitions of "realification" and "complexification". And I'm seeking to make CR formal using those definitions.

Comment: you're going to have to be more explicit about what it is you wish to "make more formal", and what about the things I've said so far is not formal enough. Because first it seemed like your linear algebra had some basic conceptual errors hence I addressed those first, but now I'm not really sure what it is you're looking for

Comment: So when we do "realification", we lose multiplication by complex numbers but for CR that doesn't matter? However, when we do "complexification", we should get $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{C}$, however like you said that space is not isomorphic to the "complexified" space

Comment: $\Bbb{R}^2$ over $\Bbb{R}$ is certainly not isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$ over $\Bbb{C}$. But, by defining $J(x,y)=(-y,x)$, we have a complex structure, so we can consider $\Bbb{R}^2$ over $\Bbb{C}$ and this is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}$ over $\Bbb{C}$.